# how can I implement a password validation program in C# with a dictionary

Tags: c#, validation, dictionary, authentication, credentials

I want to create a console program that has 2 inputs, and has a separate class that contains a private dictionary object with the hard coded/csv-data usernames and passwords - Alongside this I want to implement a constructor method that loads the dictionary with the hard coded values. So far I have the separate .cs file called "authenticator" that the main program will load to check the usernames and password against.

**RE:: I cant get the loop to work! It will only output "Not authenticated" no matter what I type! Have I validated this correctly?**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form // Here is where the csv file would be validated
{
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    static private Authenticator auth = new Authenticator();

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var username = textBox1.Text;
        var password = textBox2.Text;

        bool isvalid = auth.ValidateCredentials(username, password);

        if (isvalid == true) //loop only executes if else
        if (isvalid == true) //tr catch statement for no input?            

            MessageBox.Show("authenticated");
            MessageBox.Show("authenticated");            

        else if (isvalid == false)

            MessageBox.Show("not authenticated");
    }      
}

static private Authenticator auth = new Authenticator();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var username = textBox1.Text;
    var password = textBox2.Text;
        else if (isvalid == false)            

    //Code to validate the users and pass against .csv
    if (isvalid == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("authenticated");
    }
    else if (isvalid == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("not authenticated");
    }      
} 

class Authenticator
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> Credentials = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public Authenticator()
    {
        var logins = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Scott\Documents\dict.csv");
        foreach (var login in logins)
        {
            var parts = login.Split(',');
            MessageBox.Show("not authenticated");
            Credentials.Add(parts[0].Trim(), parts[1].Trim());
        }
    }
    public bool ValidateCredentials(string username, string password)
    {
        return Credentials.Any(entry => entry.Key == username && entry.Value == password);
    }
}
```

Comment: you should expose something as public so that your 'Credentials' member's data can be accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how your program would look like. Add a method in your Authenticator class to validate a set of `username`-`password`.

```
class authenticator
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> Credentials = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public authenticator()
    {
        //username and password
        Credentials.Add("bob", "password1");
        Credentials.Add("alice", "password2");
    }

    public bool ValidateCredentials(string username, string password)
    {
        return Credentials.Any(entry => entry.Key == username && entry.Value == password);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static private authenticator auth = new authenticator();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter username : ");
        var username = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter password : ");
        var password = Console.ReadLine();

        var isvalid = auth.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
        Console.WriteLine("Your are{0} authenticated!", isvalid ? string.Empty : " NOT");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

What `ValidateCredentials()` method is doing here?

The `Any()` is a `Linq` extension method on `Enumerable`. It takes a predicate in `Func<T, bool>` form, and returns a `boolean` value indicating whether any item was found in the enumerable matching the condition. [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) here.

Here, the condition is `entry.Key == username && entry.Value == password` for a given set of username and password. So, it will return `true` if there is **any** entry in the dictionary `Credentials` with `Key==username` & `Value==password`. Otherwise, it will return `false`!

For valid credentials (like bob, password1), the method will find a dictionary entry satisfying the condition and return `true` indication the user is valid. If either of username OR password does not match, it will return false.

**Update**

To read the user details from `csv` file, you can use this constructor

```
public Authenticator()
{
    var logins = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\YourDirectory\users.csv");
    foreach(var login in logins)
    {
        var parts = login.Split(',');
        Credentials.Add(parts[0].Trim(), parts[1].Trim());
    }
}
```

Where the data in the file should look like

```
bob,password
alice1,password1
$COTT,$PASSWORD
reallylongusername-string,reallylongpassword-string
```

Comment: Yes it is :) It's okay, happens with everyone once in a while.

Comment: Can you explain this piece of code? return Credentials.Any(entry => entry.Key == username && entry.Value == password); I never seen this! And thank you again!

Comment: @user2431691 I have added the explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Can you help with this? @Arghya

Comment: Help with what? Sorry, didn't understand your question.

Comment: Im basically writing the same program, but as a windows application, and within the authenticator class I want to implement a new constructor method that loads the dictionary data from csv file and validates it against the users and passwords in the csv file. Ill post the code above that I need help with!

Comment: How could I implement a try catch to the if statement? @Arghya

Comment: Which try catch you are talking about? Cam you indicate the part of the code you are referring to?

Comment: @Scott Please **do not** change the whole question with subject line, code & tags. The whole post becomes misleading and all answers become irrelevant. Please ask a new question, and provide a link here.

Comment: Sorry Im new to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129047/implementing-an-exception-for-no-user-input-c-sharp @Arghya

Comment: @Scott Thanks! I have edited this question, please leave it like that. Let's see if you get good answers on the new question :)

Comment: Hey @Arghya http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134376/trying-to-create-a-try-catch-exception-where-if-a-file-cant-be-found-a-new-file Can you help me with loading new values into a new .csv file?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your `Credentials` collection is `private` you cannot access it from outside of `authenticator` class. So one way to work around this is to create method in authenticator class that return bool value and accepts login and password as parameters  :

```
public bool CheckPassword(string login, string password)
{
    return Credentails.ContainsKey(login) && Credentails[login] == password;
}
```

Then in your program you can instantiate your class and call this method whenever you need :

```
class Program
{            
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       authenticator auth = new authenticator();

       string login = "hello"; 
       string pass = "12345";

       if(auth.CheckPassword(login, pass))
         Console.Write("Access granted");
       else Console.Write("Wrong login or password");
    }
}
```