# Implementing an exception for no user input

Tags: c#, exception

Below is the if statement the input boxes to the isvalid credentials, im trying to get create an exception method that will output a message box if no input is detected in the textbox's

with the code below, when nothing is entered, it will output the message "not authenticated" as well both the messages for the IsNullOrWhiteSpace. I'm trying to get it so that if nothing is entered, a messagebox will appear asking for a username and password, but I don't want the message "not Authenticated" as well if that makes sense?

How could I implement this into my code below?

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var username = textBox2.Text;
    var password = textBox1.Text;

    bool isvalid = auth.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
    {
        if (isvalid == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Authenticated!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not Authenticated!");
        }

        if (isvalid = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username is empty, please enter a username!");
        }
        if (isvalid = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Password is empty, please enter a password!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do those checks before trying to validate, and exit the method if either are blank:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Username is empty, please enter a username!");
    return;
}
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Password is empty, please enter a password!");
    return;
}

bool isvalid = auth.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
if (isvalid)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Authenticated!");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Not Authenticated!");
}
```

Note that I removed the assignment to `isValid` in your `if` statements since it's unnecessary. I also removed the `{ }` after the `bool isValid` assignment.  `{ }` is used to define a new scope, typically after an `if` or loop statement.  They din;t hurt anything here but are also not necessary.

Comment: So it wasn't working because they weren't checking first?

Comment: because `assigning` isValid instead of `comparing`

Comment: @Scott also notice that `=` are removed! You cannot compare with single `=`.

Comment: Well, you were checking for a valid combination first - since I'm assuming that a blank username or password is not valid you were seeing _that_ message box first.

Comment: @user2754599 I think the intent _was_ to assign, not just to compare.  It looks strange but it does compile.

Answer (score 0):

inside your logic I would use throwing an exception:

```
throw new System.ArgumentException("password cannot be null", "original");
```

Oh and in your if statements you should us compare operators `==` instead of assign `=`

Comment: Throwing an exception in `Button_Click` will likely stop the program.  Not sure that's the best approach here.

Comment: @DStanley that's why `button1_Click` 's logic should be moved to another method and inside button1_Click's body call it inside a try/catch. `button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){try{authenticate()}catch{MessageBox.Show('noooo');}public void authenticate(){if(succes){}else{throw new System.ArgumentException("password cannot be null", "original");}}`

Comment: I disagree with this. It isn't exceptional behavior and because of that it shouldn't be handled as such. This is a known use case and should be handled that way

Comment: @Jetti the question litteraly states `implementing an exception` and I also found the bug he actually meant so that's why