# trying to create a try catch exception where if a file can't be found a new file with values of the old file is loaded instead

Tags: c#, csv

I have a try catch exception where if the dict.csv file cant e found a messagebox will appear and a new file will be created called newdict.csv - How do I load the old value of the dict.csv file into the new file?

The values being a list of usernames and passwords?

```
    try //checks for existing dict.csv file and reads it for key and value and checks against credentials
        {

            var data = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Scott\Documents\dict.csv");//Reads all contents of a file and then closes the file once its been read
            foreach (var login in data)
            {
                var parts = login.Split(',');//creates a variable called data and loads it with the dict.csv file
                Credentials.Add(parts[0].Trim(), parts[1].Trim());//splites the key and value into [0] and [1] and trim removes leading and white space and applies ","
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)//How do I load the newdict.csv with values of dict.csv?
        {
            MessageBox.Show("dict.csv file does not exist! Creating new file called newdict.csv", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\Scott\Documents\newdict.csv "))
            Credentials.Add("bob2", "password");                          
            Credentials.Add("user", "pass");
        }
```

Comment: How can you load a file with values from a file that doesn't exist?

Comment: The new file will exist if the old one doesn't

Comment: I'm not sure if you know what you want. First you are goint to create a `newdict.csv` if `dict.csv` doesn't exist and then you want to load the contents of the not existing old file `dict.csv` into the `newdict.csv`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would be better off if you used:

```
string[] newCredentials, data, parts;
if (!File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Scott\Documents\dict.csv"))
{
    //create .csv file
    newCredentials = new string[2];
    newCredentials[0] = "Bob2,password";
    newCredentials[1] = "user,pass";
    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Scott\Documents\newdict.csv", newCredentials))
    Credentials.Add("bob2", "password");                          
    Credentials.Add("user", "pass");
}
else
{
    data = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Scott\Documents\dict.csv");
    foreach(string login in data)
    {
        parts = login.Split(',');
        Credentials.Add(parts[0].Trim(), parts[1].Trim());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I want to keep the try catch, but how would I load the new csv file with newCredentials after it has been created?

Comment: @Scott doesn't File.WriteAllLines(string path, string[] lines) work for you?

Comment: How could I add the credentials to the newdict file? @GeMaths

Comment: If you create the file "newdict" then you have to use File.AppendAllLines or File.WriteAllLines, both of them need the path of the newdict.csv and whatever lines you want to include, for example "user,pass" that's one line. If you see the code I first posted as an aswer, I include both lines in a string array, which I then pass as a parameter to the File.WriteAllLines method.